# How to specify a proprietary font with font-family property?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am considering specifying a proprietary policy with the `font-family` CSS property, e.g.

```
font-family : "Proxima Nova";
```

This is a for-fee licensed font, and the majority of my users won't have it installed. But those who do have it, will see it. So, I'm "using" a font without buying it.

I am not serving the font itself, only specifying that it be used *if available*.

Is that permitted? How should I do that?

Comment: You're not *using* the font at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Just make sure you list some alternatives, like so:

```
font-family: "Proxima Nova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

This is just to make sure that users don't fall back on a default font of a different style, like `serif` in this case.

`Helvetica Neue`, for example, is only licensed (by default - you *can* license it yourself although almost no-one does) for MacOS and iOS and therefor only available on those systems. The users that see this font have 'payed' for their license by paying for their OS (or hardware), so they can use this font without restriction. It is therefor legal. Now apart from some people who installed illegal fonts, the blame never comes to you.

You are not responsible for the displaying of a font that you did not provide. (You are responsible when you include a font with `@font-face` or other services, but not for just referencing a potential local font on a machine.)

Comment: Helvetica Neue can be licensed for any system. It's just that Apple has given us a license with the OS.

Comment: @DA Yes that is true but in general Helvetica Neue is only available to people on Apple systems as Microsoft does not license it and Linux is free and therefor licenses nothing. Nitpicking.

Comment: We may be saying the same thing, but to be clear, *anyone* can license helvetica neue and put it on their Microsoft Windows or Linux computer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's legal.

You are not using the font, the person visiting the site is using the font to view your site.